# How to run more than 6 instances of a application on a single port in Windows 7/vista

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, tcp

I have an application running on a different machine ....the application needs some info from a windows 7 machine, which is listing on a specific port.

I need to run 64 instances of the application but vista is supporting only 6 instances over the specific port.

How can I change this from 6 to 64 ...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If your client applications are all attempting to connect simultaneously, then the most likely explanation is that you are running into the TCP connection backlog limit. This is a limit on the server-side which is deliberately set to a low level on the non-server editions of Windows.

According to Microsoft ([here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/Q127144) and [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=06c60bfe-4d37-4f50-8587-8b68d32fa6ee)), the maximum backlog was 5 in NT4 Workstation and XP. I have not been able to confirm whether this is the same in Vista and Win7.

I do not believe it is possible to increase this limit without a crack. Your best workaround would be to make the client applications wait for a moment after a connection failure and try again.